# Sharepoint Designer 2013 workflow:How to send email to multiple users?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, designer-workflow

I am facing an issue of sending an email to multiple users in designer list workflow.
Having one list field of type people and group, which allows multiple section.
Requirement is I want to send an email to all those users.

I have already tried by assigning a value to one variable and then send email, but it is not working, it takes user name comma separated, not semicolon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am facing the same issue. Have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Choose option As like above image automatically taken Semicolons between Names.

Second Option

[image]

The Above action Replace , by ; in string, after that the store to variable (output). so you can use email action instead of users you select variable.

Datasource:  Workflow variables and Parameter
Field from source : Variable(output)

Comment: good solution. with the lookup filter, this is powerful.

Comment: @NagarajuPattem Can you elaborate more please? Where would I find this option is SPD2013?

Comment: This action replaces particular substring with another substring.

1. Create New SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013
2. Go to Action under Insert tab and select Replace Substring in String under Utility Actions. You will get following line in your workflow.

Replace string with string in string (Output to Variable:output)