# Assign Permissions via SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list with a text field that contains email addresses.

*Example:someone@example.com;abcd@example.com;efgh@example.com;*

Is there a way to Assign Permission to the email addresses via SharePoint designer on item created or changed workflow?

If there is only one email address it works fine.Other wise it throws the error Coercion Failed.

Please Help.

Comment: why u dont use SPGroup? put your mail-addresses into it.

Comment: Email address value varies for each list item. So the Permission is different for each list item.

Comment: check out this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflowhow-to-send-email-to-multiple-users

Comment: We did this by using a free third-party workflow action that splits the string of email addresses into an array, then create a loop in the workflow that processes each one at a time.  http://spworkflowactions.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MiladFrancis Thank u.this seems to be a valid solution. But we use 2010 workflow where we could not find replace function.

Comment: @Robin Thanks Robin!. But i should not use third party action/tools.