# Error in sending mail to more than one user through multi valued column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, email, person

I had a **Organizer** list with 2 main columns as `event` and `email`. Another list is **Problem** list which has a lookup column with look up field as event. So, a person poses problem and link all events he have problem with. I used multi-valued look up column. So, events are separated by ';'. Now, I want to mail all those organizers. But, in mail i am again using lookup from list option and assign accordingly. But, it is sending mail to only first organizer up to first semicolon only. How can I ensure that mail goes to all those multi-valued lookup organizers.

P.S. - This is my first SharePoint experience and I am using SharePoint 2013  and SharePoint 2013 Designer.

Answer (score 0):

please check this  SharePoint stackexchange post

[Sharepoint Designer 2013 workflow:How to send email to multiple users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflowhow-to-send-email-to-multiple-users)

and this  for step by step procedure

http://jenkinsblogs.com/2015/04/30/how-to-send-emails-to-multiple-users-from-lookup-list-people-picker-field-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Tarun, that was great insight. It is looking hard but I will try to implement that workflow. Also, in that blog I saw hint to hide any column which is my another problem. Can you guide me through that also. I want to hide addressed column of Problems list not to be available while creating new item.

Comment: please upvote my answer if it helps you. please check this post to hide the columns https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb

Comment: I tried to upvote. But, it is saying that your response is recorded but would not be shown publicly(since I have only 1 reputation). It requires 15 reputations as it says. :( Thanks again btw.

Comment: Please accept my solutions as answer if it solves you problem